# Aligning checkboxes in nested repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a nested repeater control and I am trying to list out the items underneath that nested repeater over a few spaces including the check box associated with it. But it seems like every other line is a checkbox without a label, can someone shed a little light?

```
<asp:Repeater ID="parentRepeater" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <br />                  
        <b>
            <input type="checkbox" id="chk_ParentProgram"  name="chk_ParentProgram" runat="server"
                value='<%# ((programsRepeat)Container.DataItem).Level == 1 ? ((programsRepeat)Container.DataItem).ProgramID.ToString() : "" %> '
                       />
            <label for="chk_ParentProgram">
              <%# ((programsRepeat)Container.DataItem).Level == 1 ? ((programsRepeat)Container.DataItem).ProgramName : "" %> 
                </label>        
        </b>
        <asp:Repeater>
            <ItemTemplate>
                 <br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                     <input type="checkbox" id="chk_ChildProgram" name="chk_Child" runat="server"
                    value='<%# ((programsRepeat)Container.DataItem).Level == 2 ? ((programsRepeat)Container.DataItem).ProgramID.ToString() + " from the child repeater" : "" %>'
                         />
                                <label for="chk_ChildProgram">
              <%# ((programsRepeat)Container.DataItem).Level == 2 ? ((programsRepeat)Container.DataItem).ProgramName : "" %> 
                </label>  
           </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

[image: Screenshot for layout]

Comment: Which dataset or datatable you are binding with your repeater. Can I have code for binding repeater

Comment: Show the flat HTML produced and also any CSS.

Comment: Contact contact=new Contact();
List<OriginalPOC> test=new List<OriginalPOC>();
List<programsRepeat> pRepeat=new List<programsRepeat>();
test=contact.getOriginalPOCPublic();
foreach (var item in test){
if (item.Level.ToString() == "1" && item.Visible != false)
{
pRepeat.Add(new programsRepeat{ ProgramID=item.PocID, ProgramName =item.PocName, Level = item.Level });   
}
if (item.Level.ToString()== "2" && item.Visible != false)
{
pRepeat.Add(new programsRepeat{ProgramID=item.PocID, ProgramName =item.PocName, Level=item.Level }); 
}
}
parentRepeater.DataSource = pRepeat;
parentRepeater.DataBind();

Comment: Please add the generated HTML . It will help us to understand the issue more

Answer (score 0):

The problem is whether you have a valid value or empty sting for `(programsRepeat)Container.DataItem).ProgramID.ToString()` you still rendering the checkbox like below

```
<input type="checkbox" value="" />
```

`This will render the empty checkbox.`

Better check the value and render the checkbox like

```
<% if((programsRepeat)Container.DataItem).Level == 2 && 
 ((programsRepeat)Container.DataItem).ProgramID!="")
{
 //not sure about the inline syntax here. 
 //add checkbox code
}
%>
```

[Inline Syntax Reference](http://weblogs.asp.net/ahmedmoosa/archive/2010/10/06/embedded-code-and-inline-server-tags.aspx) or check [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976112)